# Galaxy Phone S7 VR is all looking straight down and will not move

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, 3d, virtual-reality

I'm developing a Unity VR app, which has been working an hour ago.  3D Video and the camera moved when I moved my head.

Recently though, the VR app is always pointing down.  I.e. staring at the floor.  Moving the phone (or my head) has no reaction.  The game or app still runs, but I no longer can move the view.

I thought this was a bug, but it turns out **all the VR apps on my phone are now  staring at the ground**.  Is there a setting on my Galaxy S7 phone that might cause this?  There were no updates or app setting changes between when I ran it and it was working to when it wasn't.  At least nothing I noticed.

Android Version 7.0. 
Device: SAMSUNG-SM-G930A

As a side note, it is possible that all the apps I'm running were made in Unity and this may be a Unity Bug, but I have my doubts.

Unity Settings: 
 - Version: 5.6.2f1
 - Google VR SDK Version: 1.60.0
 - API: Android 7.0 (24)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was an OS/Driver bug of some type.  Restarting worked.  I should have listened to my IT Duck's first bit of advice.  "Have you tried restarting?"